# In Sonar, how do I view test coverage by tests?

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco

I know I can drill down in the coverage widget on the dashboard and see the code and branch coverage. However, I would like to see what source files and lines of code are covered by each individual test. It's looking like Sonar doesn't support this the other way around. If it's not supported, is there a way I can configure Sonar to do such? FYI, we are using JaCoCo for test coverage right now. Any info greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably doesn't help much, but I'm pretty sure that this is not supported.

Sonar will only allow you to view the results by tested class, not by test class.

One way to work around this would be to run Sonar multiple times, once for each test class, but that's probably not easy to do and probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. The only way to show coverage for one test class is to disable all other test classes.... Not terribly practical.

Comment: Bummer, I don't think I try that. I looked into adding a feature request and found somebody beat me to it! Vote it up :) http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2501